# Is this problem in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I am new in complexity theory and have a doubt.
If you have a language (alphabet) L (for example {"a";"b";"Y","0","1","◄"}) and a Dictionary D (for example {"abY";"Ú■";"ba";"000001◄";"FFG","342"}) Output all the words in D that can be generated by the symbols in L So, for the example above a program will output: "abY";"ba";"000001◄" Question is: is this problem in NP?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your problem isn't a decision problem. NP is a class of decision problems. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem).

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes a category error. Your problem is an enumeration problem ("List all the things with property X") but **NP** is a class of decision problems ("Does the input have property X?").

In any case, there is an obvious deterministic polynomial time algorithm for your problem. Just check each character of each string against $L$. If $L$ is fixed, this runs in linear time; if it's a part of the input, it runs in quadratic time.